# window.external.AddFavorite on IE8/9

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I'm using the function `window.external.AddFavorite(URL, title)`.
This works properly on IE6 and IE7 but not on IE8 or IE9?
no error is shown and the page doesn't get added to Favorites.

Comment: I think modern browsers disallowing adding bookmarks via JavaScript for security reasons.  You can instead prompt the user to press `Ctrl+D`.

Comment: It is usually a good idea to post some of your code to make your post more valuable.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535926%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. For security reasons, the
>   AddFavorite method must be called as a response to a user-initiated
>   action, such a mouse click. If called from a different context, such
>   as the onload event of the body element, the AddFavorite method fails
>   silently.

So if you do it on a mouse click, then the user should get prompted.